# How can I get query string values in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, url, plugins, query-string

Is there a plugin-less way of retrieving [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) values via jQuery (or without)?

If so, how? If not, is there a plugin which can do so?

Comment: I use the plugin *getUrlParam* described in *[jQuery-Plugin – getUrlParam (version 2)](http://www.mathias-bank.de/2007/04/21/jquery-plugin-geturlparam-version-2/)*.

Comment: I like dojo's [queryToObject](https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/493fadc6b0382690e8b3800f2b30b345f8e538ad/_base/xhr.js#L166). The function could easily be plucked from the framework if you're on a diet.

Comment: A *plain javascript* solution without RegEx: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-variables/

Comment: Although the top solution to the question deserves its popularity because of its excellent observation that jQuery is not needed, its method of creating new regular expressions and re-parsing the query string for every parameter desired is extremely inefficient. Far more efficient (and versatile) solutions have been in existence for a long time, for example within this article reprinted here: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/11877_3755006_3/How-to-Use-a-JavaScript-Query-String-Parser.htm

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript query string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647259/javascript-query-string)

Comment: Joseph, the "excellent observation that jQuery is not needed"? Of course it's not needed. Everything jQuery does, it does using JavaScript. People don't use jQuery because it does stuff that JavaScript can't do. The point of jQuery is convenience.

Answer (score 10482, accepted):

Use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams#Browser_compatibility) to get parameters from the query string.

For example:

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const myParam = urlParams.get('myParam');
```

**Update: Jan-2022**

Using [`Proxy()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) is [faster](https://jsben.ch/MeP5G) than using [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) and better supported.

This approach comes with the caveat that you can no longer iterate over query parameters.

```
const params = new Proxy(new URLSearchParams(window.location.search), {
  get: (searchParams, prop) => searchParams.get(prop),
});
// Get the value of "some_key" in eg "https://example.com/?some_key=some_value"
let value = params.some_key; // "some_value"
```

**Update: June-2021**

For a specific case when you need all query params:

```
const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const params = Object.fromEntries(urlSearchParams.entries());
```

**Update: Sep-2018**

You can use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams#Browser_compatibility) which is simple and has [decent (but not complete) browser support](https://caniuse.com/urlsearchparams).

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const myParam = urlParams.get('myParam');
```

**Original**

You don't need jQuery for that purpose. You can use just some pure JavaScript:

```
function getParameterByName(name, url = window.location.href) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
    var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
```

**Usage:**

```
// query string: ?foo=lorem&bar=&baz
var foo = getParameterByName('foo'); // "lorem"
var bar = getParameterByName('bar'); // "" (present with empty value)
var baz = getParameterByName('baz'); // "" (present with no value)
var qux = getParameterByName('qux'); // null (absent)
```

NOTE: If a parameter is present several times (`?foo=lorem&foo=ipsum`), you will get the first value (`lorem`). There is no standard about this and usages vary, see for example this question: [Authoritative position of duplicate HTTP GET query keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746507/authoritative-position-of-duplicate-http-get-query-keys).

NOTE: The function is case-sensitive. If you prefer case-insensitive parameter name, [add 'i' modifier to RegExp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939715/case-insensitive-regex-in-javascript)

NOTE: If you're getting a no-useless-escape eslint error, you can replace `name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');` with `name = name.replace(/[[\]]/g, '\\$&')`.

---

This is an update based on the new [URLSearchParams specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to achieve the same result more succinctly. See answer titled "[URLSearchParams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript/901144#12151322)" below.

Comment: I notice that `Object.fromEntries(urlSearchParams)` yields the same result. So we don't actually need the `.entries()`

Comment: June-2021 and Proxy solutions don't work with SPA (Singla Page Application). SPA changes de content of the page and can even change the URL relative path (adding query strings for example).

Comment: How can you iterate over the values ​​dynamically, with that Proxy structure?

Comment: Need to be careful here `decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));` when you get base64 string from URL. Because the Base64 string can contain the "+" character. Removing this character will corrupt the base64 string.

Comment: @DMAVE If you want to iterate over the parameters, you need to use an iterator such as  [`.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries), **OR** to enumerate all the keys yourself, which is easier than it sounds, [for example this little solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript/21152762#21152762).

Comment: @Qwerty in fact all the performance gains from "new Proxy(new URLSearchParams)" would be lost.

Comment: @DMAVE Of course.

Comment: Maybe a lame, tiny detail but is there any reason you need a comma after searchParams.get(prop)?

Comment: @JeffThompson, trailing commas are allowed but not required. They make it easier for developers to add new entries to the object without having to edit any of the existing entries' lines.

Comment: Jan-2022: if you need all values of the same parameter name as an array then use `searchParams.getAll(prop)`.

Comment: Please note that using Proxy will return a Proxy – not an Object - why e.g. hasOwnProperty does not exist - IMO a marginal performance gain (common use case scenario) should not precede expected return :)

Comment: If you're using AngularJS-routing, `function getParameterByName(name, url = decodeURIComponent(window.location.href)) {` since it doesn't support querystring and also since `?`'s are replaced by `%3F`

Comment: You are probably looking for the Sept-2018 answer.

Comment: Why would not use something like this: 

```const param = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
param.get('paramName')```

Comment: Proxy is NOT more performant... when reading the code. Or debugging the weird issues that result from not having a plain old JS object. When you determine that parsing query params is a bottleneck for your application, then you can use Proxy (or maybe ask why you have millions of query params in your URL). Until then, use clear and comprehensible Object.fromEntries().

Comment: I have read a bit about proxy. I am no convinced why using a proxy is warranted here. If it is for caching, urlParams in your 3rd example should be adequate, no?

Comment: If anyone is curious how to get the value with the new Proxy implementation here's an example with typescript:


const queryParams = new Proxy(new URLSearchParams(window.location.search), {
 get: (searchParams, prop) => searchParams.get(prop as string),
});
// example https://localhost:3000?query_param_from_url=hello
const queryValue = queryParams['query_param_from_url']:
console.log({queryValue})

Comment: I'm from 2024. Just benchmarked `URLSearchParams` against regex, and it's 1.5X slower

Answer (score 1779):

Some of the solutions posted here are inefficient. Repeating the regular expression search every time the script needs to access a parameter is completely unnecessary, one single function to split up the parameters into an associative-array style object is enough. If you're not working with the HTML 5 History API, this is only necessary once per page load.  The other suggestions here also fail to decode the URL correctly.

```
var urlParams;
(window.onpopstate = function () {
    var match,
        pl     = /\+/g,  // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
        search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
        decode = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, " ")); },
        query  = window.location.search.substring(1);
  
    urlParams = {};
    while (match = search.exec(query))
       urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
})();
```

Example querystring:

> `?i=main&mode=front&sid=de8d49b78a85a322c4155015fdce22c4&enc=+Hello%20&empty`

Result:

```js
 urlParams = {
    enc: " Hello ",
    i: "main",
    mode: "front",
    sid: "de8d49b78a85a322c4155015fdce22c4",
    empty: ""
}

alert(urlParams["mode"]);
// -> "front"

alert("empty" in urlParams);
// -> true
```

This could easily be improved upon to handle array-style query strings too.  An example of this is [here](http://jsbin.com/adali3/2), but since array-style parameters aren't defined in [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) I won't pollute this answer with the source code. [For those interested in a "polluted" version, look at campbeln's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript/23401756#23401756).

Also, as pointed out in the comments, `;` is a legal delimiter for `key=value` pairs.  It would require a more complicated regex to handle `;` or `&`, which I think is unnecessary because it's rare that `;` is used and I would say even more unlikely that both would be used.  If you need to support `;` instead of `&`, just swap them in the regex.

---

If you're using a server-side preprocessing language, you might want to use its native JSON functions to do the heavy lifting for you.  For example, in PHP you can write:

```
<script>var urlParams = <?php echo json_encode($_GET, JSON_HEX_TAG);?>;</script>
```

Much simpler!

#UPDATED

> A new capability would be to retrieve repeated params as following `myparam=1&myparam=2`. There is not a *specification*, however, most of the current approaches follow the generation of an array.

```
myparam = ["1", "2"]
```

So, this is the approach to manage it:

```
let urlParams = {};
(window.onpopstate = function () {
    let match,
        pl = /\+/g,  // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
        search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
        decode = function (s) {
            return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, " "));
        },
        query = window.location.search.substring(1);

    while (match = search.exec(query)) {
        if (decode(match[1]) in urlParams) {
            if (!Array.isArray(urlParams[decode(match[1])])) {
                urlParams[decode(match[1])] = [urlParams[decode(match[1])]];
            }
            urlParams[decode(match[1])].push(decode(match[2]));
        } else {
            urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: This worked like a Charm to fetch the live URL on page load every single time:-)

Comment: Very nice! However, I suggest to introduce local variables `let parameterKey = decode(match[1]); let parameterValue = decode(match[2]);`. This makes it more obvious what is happening IMHO.

Comment: I used this one as fallback to the top answer, as after that this is the most complete solution

Answer (score 1326):

## ES2015 (ES6)

```
getQueryStringParams = query => {
    return query
        ? (/^[?#]/.test(query) ? query.slice(1) : query)
            .split('&')
            .reduce((params, param) => {
                    let [key, value] = param.split('=');
                    params[key] = value ? decodeURIComponent(value.replace(/\+/g, ' ')) : '';
                    return params;
                }, {}
            )
        : {}
};
```

---

### Without jQuery

```
var qs = (function(a) {
    if (a == "") return {};
    var b = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
    {
        var p=a[i].split('=', 2);
        if (p.length == 1)
            b[p[0]] = "";
        else
            b[p[0]] = decodeURIComponent(p[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    return b;
})(window.location.search.substr(1).split('&'));
```

With an URL like `?topic=123&name=query+string`, the following will return:

```
qs["topic"];    // 123
qs["name"];     // query string
qs["nothere"];  // undefined (object)
```

---

### Google method

Tearing Google's code I found the method they use: `getUrlParameters`

```
function (b) {
    var c = typeof b === "undefined";
    if (a !== h && c) return a;
    for (var d = {}, b = b || k[B][vb], e = b[p]("?"), f = b[p]("#"), b = (f === -1 ? b[Ya](e + 1) : [b[Ya](e + 1, f - e - 1), "&", b[Ya](f + 1)][K](""))[z]("&"), e = i.dd ? ia : unescape, f = 0, g = b[w]; f < g; ++f) {
        var l = b[f][p]("=");
        if (l !== -1) {
            var q = b[f][I](0, l),
                l = b[f][I](l + 1),
                l = l[Ca](/\+/g, " ");
            try {
                d[q] = e(l)
            } catch (A) {}
        }
    }
    c && (a = d);
    return d
}
```

It is obfuscated, but it is understandable. It does not work because some variables are undefined.

They start to look for parameters on the url from `?` and also from the hash `#`. Then for each parameter they split in the equal sign `b[f][p]("=")` (which looks like `indexOf`, they use the position of the char to get the key/value). Having it split they check whether the parameter has a value or not, if it has then they store the value of `d`, otherwise they just continue.

In the end the object `d` is returned, handling escaping and the `+` sign. This object is just like mine, it has the same behavior.

---

My method as a **jQuery plugin**

```
(function($) {
    $.QueryString = (function(paramsArray) {
        let params = {};

        for (let i = 0; i < paramsArray.length; ++i)
        {
            let param = paramsArray[i]
                .split('=', 2);
            
            if (param.length !== 2)
                continue;
            
            params[param[0]] = decodeURIComponent(param[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }
            
        return params;
    })(window.location.search.substr(1).split('&'))
})(jQuery);
```

Usage

```
//Get a param
$.QueryString.param
//-or-
$.QueryString["param"]
//This outputs something like...
//"val"

//Get all params as object
$.QueryString
//This outputs something like...
//Object { param: "val", param2: "val" }

//Set a param (only in the $.QueryString object, doesn't affect the browser's querystring)
$.QueryString.param = "newvalue"
//This doesn't output anything, it just updates the $.QueryString object

//Convert object into string suitable for url a querystring (Requires jQuery)
$.param($.QueryString)
//This outputs something like...
//"param=newvalue&param2=val"

//Update the url/querystring in the browser's location bar with the $.QueryString object
history.replaceState({}, '', "?" + $.param($.QueryString));
//-or-
history.pushState({}, '', "?" + $.param($.QueryString));
```

---

### [Performance test (split method against regex method)](http://jsperf.com/querystring-with-javascript) ([jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/))

Preparation code: methods declaration

#### Split test code

```
var qs = window.GetQueryString(query);

var search = qs["q"];
var value = qs["value"];
var undef = qs["undefinedstring"];
```

#### Regex test code

```
var search = window.getParameterByName("q");
var value = window.getParameterByName("value");
var undef = window.getParameterByName("undefinedstring");
```

**Testing in Firefox 4.0 x86 on Windows Server 2008 R2 / 7 x64**

- **Split method**: 144,780 ±2.17% fastest
- **Regex method**: 13,891 ±0.85% | 90% slower

Comment: Amasing research. I recommend you to replace "substr" with "substring" in order to avoid the deprecated warning in various editors (could be the only explanation why 8 people downvoted this method, except insanity).

Answer (score 725):

## URLSearchParams

Firefox 44+, Opera 36+, Edge 17+, Safari 10.3+ and Chrome 49+ support the [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) API:

- [Chrome Announcement and details](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/01/urlsearchparams)
- [Opera Announcement and details](https://dev.opera.com/blog/opera-36/)
- [Firefox Announcement and details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/44#Miscellaneous)

There is a google-suggested **[URLSearchParams polyfill](https://github.com/WebReflection/url-search-params)** for the stable versions of IE.

It is not standardized by [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-url-1-20141209/#interface-urlsearchparams), but it is a living standard by [WhatWG](https://url.spec.whatwg.org).

You can use it on `location`:

```
const params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
```

or

```
const params = (new URL(location)).searchParams;
```

Or of course on any URL:

```
const url = new URL('https://example.com?foo=1&bar=2');
const params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
```

You can get params also using a shorthand `.searchParams` property on the URL object, like this:

```
const params = new URL('https://example.com?foo=1&bar=2').searchParams;
params.get('foo'); // "1"
params.get('bar'); // "2"
```

You read/set parameters through the `get(KEY)`, `set(KEY, VALUE)`, `append(KEY, VALUE)` API. You can also iterate over all values `for (let p of params) {}`.

A [reference implementation](https://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/platform/URLParser.cpp) and a [sample page](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/urlsearchparams/) are available for auditing and testing.

Comment: const params = new URL(location.href).searchParams; to not rely on static text for the url

Comment: @chri3g91 in fact, as the answers shows, you can use `const params = new URL(location).searchParams;`

Answer (score 681):

Improved version of [Artem Barger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-values-with-jquery/901144#901144):

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)').exec(window.location.search);
    return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
```

For more information on improvement see: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/bujs-1-getparameterbyname/

Answer (score 402):

Just another recommendation. The plugin *[Purl](https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser)* allows to retrieve all parts of URL, including anchor, host, etc.

It can be used with or without jQuery.

Usage is very simple and cool:

```
var url = $.url('http://example.com/folder/dir/index.html?item=value'); // jQuery version
var url = purl('http://example.com/folder/dir/index.html?item=value'); // plain JS version
url.attr('protocol'); // returns 'http'
url.attr('path'); // returns '/folder/dir/index.html'
```

However, as of Nov 11, 2014, Purl is no longer maintained and the author recommends using [URI.js](https://github.com/medialize/URI.js) instead.  The jQuery plugin is different in that it focuses on elements - for usage with strings, just use `URI` directly, with or without jQuery.  Similar code would look as such, fuller docs [here](http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/docs.html):

```
var url = new URI('http://example.com/folder/dir/index.html?item=value'); // plain JS version
url.protocol(); // returns 'http'
url.path(); // returns '/folder/dir/index.html'
```

Answer (score 263):

## *tl;dr*

A quick, **complete solution**, which handles **multivalued keys** and **encoded characters**.

```
// using ES5   (200 characters)
var qd = {};
if (location.search) location.search.substr(1).split("&").forEach(function(item) {var s = item.split("="), k = s[0], v = s[1] && decodeURIComponent(s[1]); (qd[k] = qd[k] || []).push(v)})

// using ES6   (23 characters cooler)
var qd = {};
if (location.search) location.search.substr(1).split`&`.forEach(item => {let [k,v] = item.split`=`; v = v && decodeURIComponent(v); (qd[k] = qd[k] || []).push(v)})

// as a function with reduce
function getQueryParams() {
  return location.search
    ? location.search.substr(1).split`&`.reduce((qd, item) => {let [k,v] = item.split`=`; v = v && decodeURIComponent(v); (qd[k] = qd[k] || []).push(v); return qd}, {})
    : {}
}
```

##### Multi-lined:

```
var qd = {};
if (location.search) location.search.substr(1).split("&").forEach(function(item) {
    var s = item.split("="),
        k = s[0],
        v = s[1] && decodeURIComponent(s[1]); //  null-coalescing / short-circuit
    //(k in qd) ? qd[k].push(v) : qd[k] = [v]
    (qd[k] = qd[k] || []).push(v) // null-coalescing / short-circuit
})
```

What is all this code...
*["null-coalescing"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/476436/985454), [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation)

ES6 [Destructuring assignments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), [Template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_template_literals)*
####Example:

```
"?a=1&b=0&c=3&d&e&a=5&a=t%20e%20x%20t&e=http%3A%2F%2Fw3schools.com%2Fmy%20test.asp%3Fname%3Dståle%26car%3Dsaab"
> qd
a: ["1", "5", "t e x t"]
b: ["0"]
c: ["3"]
d: [undefined]
e: [undefined, "http://w3schools.com/my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab"]

> qd.a[1]    // "5"
> qd["a"][1] // "5"
```

---

## Read more... about the Vanilla JavaScript solution.

*To access different parts of a URL use `location.(search|hash)`*

### Easiest (dummy) solution

```
var queryDict = {};
location.search.substr(1).split("&").forEach(function(item) {queryDict[item.split("=")[0]] = item.split("=")[1]})
```

- Handles **empty keys** correctly.
- Overrides **multi-keys** with **last** value found.

```
"?a=1&b=0&c=3&d&e&a=5"
> queryDict
a: "5"
b: "0"
c: "3"
d: undefined
e: undefined
```

### Multi-valued keys

Simple key check `(item in dict) ? dict.item.push(val) : dict.item = [val]`

```
var qd = {};
location.search.substr(1).split("&").forEach(function(item) {(item.split("=")[0] in qd) ? qd[item.split("=")[0]].push(item.split("=")[1]) : qd[item.split("=")[0]] = [item.split("=")[1]]})
```

- Now returns **arrays** instead.
- Access values by `qd.key[index]` or `qd[key][index]`

```
> qd
a: ["1", "5"]
b: ["0"]
c: ["3"]
d: [undefined]
e: [undefined]
```

### Encoded characters?

Use `decodeURIComponent()` for the second *or both* splits.

```
var qd = {};
location.search.substr(1).split("&").forEach(function(item) {var k = item.split("=")[0], v = decodeURIComponent(item.split("=")[1]); (k in qd) ? qd[k].push(v) : qd[k] = [v]})
```

####Example:

```
"?a=1&b=0&c=3&d&e&a=5&a=t%20e%20x%20t&e=http%3A%2F%2Fw3schools.com%2Fmy%20test.asp%3Fname%3Dståle%26car%3Dsaab"
> qd
a: ["1", "5", "t e x t"]
b: ["0"]
c: ["3"]
d: ["undefined"]  // decodeURIComponent(undefined) returns "undefined" !!!*
e: ["undefined", "http://w3schools.com/my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab"]
```

---

# From comments
**\*!!!** Please note, that `decodeURIComponent(undefined)` returns string `"undefined"`. The solution lies in a simple usage of [`&&`][5], which ensures that `decodeURIComponent()` is not called on undefined values. _(See the "complete solution" at the top.)_

```
v = v && decodeURIComponent(v);
```

If the querystring is empty (`location.search == ""`), the result is somewhat misleading `qd == {"": undefined}`. It is suggested to check the querystring before launching the parsing function likeso:

```
if (location.search) location.search.substr(1).split("&").forEach(...)
```

Answer (score 226):

Roshambo on snipplr.com has a simple script to achieve this described in *[Get URL Parameters with jQuery | Improved](http://snipplr.com/view/26662/get-url-parameters-with-jquery--improved/)*. With his script you also easily get to pull out just the parameters you want.

Here's the gist:

```
$.urlParam = function(name, url) {
    if (!url) {
     url = window.location.href;
    }
    var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(url);
    if (!results) {
        return undefined;
    }
    return results[1] || undefined;
}
```

Then just get your parameters from the query string.

So if the URL/query string was `xyz.example/index.html?lang=de`.

Just call `var langval = $.urlParam('lang');`, and you've got it.

UZBEKJON has a great blog post on this as well, *[Get URL parameters & values with jQuery](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html)*.

Answer (score 172):

If you're using jQuery, you can use a library, such as [jQuery BBQ: Back Button & Query Library](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/).

> ...jQuery BBQ provides a full `.deparam()` method, along with both hash state management, and fragment / query string parse and merge utility methods.

Edit: Adding Deparam Example:

```js
 var DeparamExample = function() {
            var params = $.deparam.querystring();

            //nameofparam is the name of a param from url
            //code below will get param if ajax refresh with hash
            if (typeof params.nameofparam == 'undefined') {
                params = jQuery.deparam.fragment(window.location.href);
            }
            
            if (typeof params.nameofparam != 'undefined') {
                var paramValue = params.nameofparam.toString();
                  
            }
        };
```

If you want to just use plain JavaScript, you could use...

```js
var getParamValue = (function() {
    var params;
    var resetParams = function() {
            var query = window.location.search;
            var regex = /[?&;](.+?)=([^&;]+)/g;
            var match;

            params = {};

            if (query) {
                while (match = regex.exec(query)) {
                    params[match[1]] = decodeURIComponent(match[2]);
                }
            }    
        };

    window.addEventListener
    && window.addEventListener('popstate', resetParams);

    resetParams();

    return function(param) {
        return params.hasOwnProperty(param) ? params[param] : null;
    }

})();​
```

Because of the new HTML History API and specifically `history.pushState()` and `history.replaceState()`, the URL can change which will invalidate the cache of parameters and their values.

This version will update its internal cache of parameters each time the history changes.

Answer (score 103):

Just use two **splits**:

```
function get(n) {
    var half = location.search.split(n + '=')[1];
    return half !== undefined ? decodeURIComponent(half.split('&')[0]) : null;
}
```

I was reading all the previous and more complete answers. But I think that is the simplest and faster method. You can check in this jsPerf [benchmark](http://jsperf.com/querystring-with-javascript/9)

To solve the problem in Rup's comment, add a conditional split by changing the first line to the two below. But absolute accuracy means it's now slower than regexp (see [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/querystring-with-javascript/10)).

```
function get(n) {
    var half = location.search.split('&' + n + '=')[1];
    if (!half) half = location.search.split('?' + n + '=')[1];
    return half !== undefined ? decodeURIComponent(half.split('&')[0]) : null;
}
```

So if you know you won't run into Rup's counter-case, this wins. Otherwise, regexp.

> *Or* if you have control of the querystring and can guarantee that a value you are trying to get will never contain any URL encoded
>   characters (having these in a value would be a bad idea) - you can use
>   the following slightly more simplified and readable version of the 1st option:
>
> ```
>     function getQueryStringValueByName(name) {
>         var queryStringFromStartOfValue = location.search.split(name + '=')[1];
>          return queryStringFromStartOfValue !== undefined ? queryStringFromStartOfValue.split('&')[0] : null;
> ```

Answer (score 98):

Here's my stab at making Andy E's excellent solution into a full fledged jQuery plugin:

```
;(function ($) {
    $.extend({      
        getQueryString: function (name) {           
            function parseParams() {
                var params = {},
                    e,
                    a = /\+/g,  // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
                    r = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
                    d = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(a, " ")); },
                    q = window.location.search.substring(1);

                while (e = r.exec(q))
                    params[d(e[1])] = d(e[2]);

                return params;
            }

            if (!this.queryStringParams)
                this.queryStringParams = parseParams(); 

            return this.queryStringParams[name];
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

The syntax is:

```
var someVar = $.getQueryString('myParam');
```

Best of both worlds!

Answer (score 79):

If you're doing more URL manipulation than simply parsing the querystring, you may find [URI.js](http://medialize.github.com/URI.js/) helpful. It is a library for manipulating URLs - and comes with all the bells and whistles. (Sorry for self-advertising here)

to convert your querystring into a map:

```
var data = URI('?foo=bar&bar=baz&foo=world').query(true);
data == {
  "foo": ["bar", "world"],
  "bar": "baz"
}
```

(URI.js also "fixes" bad querystrings like `?&foo&&bar=baz&` to `?foo&bar=baz`)

Answer (score 66):

I like [Ryan Phelan's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3867610/632117). But I don't see any point of extending jQuery for that? There is no usage of jQuery functionality.

On the other hand, I like the built-in function in Google Chrome: window.location.getParameter.

So why not to use this? Okay, other browsers don't have. So let's create this function if it does not exist:

```
if (!window.location.getParameter ) {
  window.location.getParameter = function(key) {
    function parseParams() {
        var params = {},
            e,
            a = /\+/g,  // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
            r = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
            d = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(a, " ")); },
            q = window.location.search.substring(1);

        while (e = r.exec(q))
            params[d(e[1])] = d(e[2]);

        return params;
    }

    if (!this.queryStringParams)
        this.queryStringParams = parseParams(); 

    return this.queryStringParams[key];
  };
}
```

This function is more or less from Ryan Phelan, but it is wrapped differently: clear name and no dependencies of other javascript libraries. [More about this function on my blog](http://sharepointkunskap.wordpress.com/2012/01/11/get-url-parameters-with-javascript/).

Answer (score 60):

Here is a fast way to get an object similar to the PHP [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) array:

```
function get_query(){
    var url = location.search;
    var qs = url.substring(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0, result = {}; i < qs.length; i++){
        qs[i] = qs[i].split('=');
        result[qs[i][0]] = decodeURIComponent(qs[i][1]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
var $_GET = get_query();
```

For the query string `x=5&y&z=hello&x=6` this returns the object:

```
{
  x: "6",
  y: undefined,
  z: "hello"
}
```

Answer (score 59):

Keep it simple in plain JavaScript code:

```
function qs(key) {
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars[key];
}
```

Call it from anywhere in the JavaScript code:

```
var result = qs('someKey');
```

Answer (score 45):

These are all great answers, but I needed something a bit more robust, and thought you all might like to have what I created.

It is a simple library method that does dissection and manipulation of URL parameters. The static method has the following sub methods that can be called on the subject URL:

- getHost
- getPath
- getHash
- setHash
- getParams
- getQuery
- setParam
- getParam
- hasParam
- removeParam

Example:

```
URLParser(url).getParam('myparam1')
```

---

```
var url = "http://www.example.com/folder/mypage.html?myparam1=1&myparam2=2#something";

function URLParser(u){
    var path="",query="",hash="",params;
    if(u.indexOf("#") > 0){
        hash = u.substr(u.indexOf("#") + 1);
        u = u.substr(0 , u.indexOf("#"));
    }
    if(u.indexOf("?") > 0){
        path = u.substr(0 , u.indexOf("?"));
        query = u.substr(u.indexOf("?") + 1);
        params= query.split('&');
    }else
        path = u;
    return {
        getHost: function(){
            var hostexp = /\/\/([\w.-]*)/;
            var match = hostexp.exec(path);
            if (match != null && match.length > 1)
                return match[1];
            return "";
        },
        getPath: function(){
            var pathexp = /\/\/[\w.-]*(?:\/([^?]*))/;
            var match = pathexp.exec(path);
            if (match != null && match.length > 1)
                return match[1];
            return "";
        },
        getHash: function(){
            return hash;
        },
        getParams: function(){
            return params
        },
        getQuery: function(){
            return query;
        },
        setHash: function(value){
            if(query.length > 0)
                query = "?" + query;
            if(value.length > 0)
                query = query + "#" + value;
            return path + query;
        },
        setParam: function(name, value){
            if(!params){
                params= new Array();
            }
            params.push(name + '=' + value);
            for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                if(query.length > 0)
                    query += "&";
                query += params[i];
            }
            if(query.length > 0)
                query = "?" + query;
            if(hash.length > 0)
                query = query + "#" + hash;
            return path + query;
        },
        getParam: function(name){
            if(params){
                for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                    var pair = params[i].split('=');
                    if (decodeURIComponent(pair[0]) == name)
                        return decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
                }
            }
            console.log('Query variable %s not found', name);
        },
        hasParam: function(name){
            if(params){
                for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                    var pair = params[i].split('=');
                    if (decodeURIComponent(pair[0]) == name)
                        return true;
                }
            }
            console.log('Query variable %s not found', name);
        },
        removeParam: function(name){
            query = "";
            if(params){
                var newparams = new Array();
                for (var i = 0;i < params.length;i++) {
                    var pair = params[i].split('=');
                    if (decodeURIComponent(pair[0]) != name)
                          newparams .push(params[i]);
                }
                params = newparams;
                for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                    if(query.length > 0)
                        query += "&";
                    query += params[i];
                }
            }
            if(query.length > 0)
                query = "?" + query;
            if(hash.length > 0)
                query = query + "#" + hash;
            return path + query;
        },
    }
}

document.write("Host: " + URLParser(url).getHost() + '<br>');
document.write("Path: " + URLParser(url).getPath() + '<br>');
document.write("Query: " + URLParser(url).getQuery() + '<br>');
document.write("Hash: " + URLParser(url).getHash() + '<br>');
document.write("Params Array: " + URLParser(url).getParams() + '<br>');
document.write("Param: " + URLParser(url).getParam('myparam1') + '<br>');
document.write("Has Param: " + URLParser(url).hasParam('myparam1') + '<br>');

document.write(url + '<br>');

// Remove the first parameter
url = URLParser(url).removeParam('myparam1');
document.write(url + ' - Remove the first parameter<br>');

// Add a third parameter
url = URLParser(url).setParam('myparam3',3);
document.write(url + ' - Add a third parameter<br>');

// Remove the second parameter
url = URLParser(url).removeParam('myparam2');
document.write(url + ' - Remove the second parameter<br>');

// Add a hash
url = URLParser(url).setHash('newhash');
document.write(url + ' - Set Hash<br>');

// Remove the last parameter
url = URLParser(url).removeParam('myparam3');
document.write(url + ' - Remove the last parameter<br>');

// Remove a parameter that doesn't exist
url = URLParser(url).removeParam('myparam3');
document.write(url + ' - Remove a parameter that doesn\"t exist<br>');
```

Answer (score 45):

From [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils/search#Get_the_value_of_a_single_search_param):

```
function loadPageVar (sVar) {
  return unescape(window.location.search.replace(new RegExp("^(?:.*[&\\?]" + escape(sVar).replace(/[\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "(?:\\=([^&]*))?)?.*$", "i"), "$1"));
}

alert(loadPageVar("name"));
```

Answer (score 41):

Code golf:

```
var a = location.search&&location.search.substr(1).replace(/\+/gi," ").split("&");
for (var i in a) {
    var s = a[i].split("=");
    a[i]  = a[unescape(s[0])] = unescape(s[1]);
}
```

Display it!

```
for (i in a) {
    document.write(i + ":" + a[i] + "<br/>");   
};
```

On my Mac: `test.htm?i=can&has=cheezburger` displays

```
0:can
1:cheezburger
i:can
has:cheezburger
```

Answer (score 40):

I use regular expressions a lot, but not for that.

It seems easier and more efficient to me to read the query string once in my application, and build an object from all the key/value pairs like:

```
var search = function() {
  var s = window.location.search.substr(1),
    p = s.split(/\&/), l = p.length, kv, r = {};
  if (l === 0) {return false;}
  while (l--) {
    kv = p[l].split(/\=/);
    r[kv[0]] = decodeURIComponent(kv[1] || '') || true;
  }
  return r;
}();
```

For a URL like `http://example.com?param1=val1&param2=val2` you can get their value later in your code as `search.param1` and `search.param2`.

Answer (score 39):

```
function GET() {
        var data = [];
        for(x = 0; x < arguments.length; ++x)
            data.push(location.href.match(new RegExp("/\?".concat(arguments[x],"=","([^\n&]*)")))[1])
                return data;
    }


example:
data = GET("id","name","foo");
query string : ?id=3&name=jet&foo=b
returns:
    data[0] // 3
    data[1] // jet
    data[2] // b
or
    alert(GET("id")[0]) // return 3
```

Answer (score 39):

Roshambo jQuery method wasn't taking care of decode URL

> http://snipplr.com/view/26662/get-url-parameters-with-jquery--improved/

Just added that capability also while adding in  the return statement

```
return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " ")) || 0;
```

Now you can find the updated gist:

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
if (!results) { return 0; }
return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " ")) || 0;
}
```

Answer (score 37):

Here's my edit to [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript/3855394#3855394) - with added ability to parse query strings with keys without values.

```
var url = 'http://sb.com/reg/step1?param';
var qs = (function(a) {
    if (a == "") return {};
    var b = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        var p=a[i].split('=', 2);
        if (p[1]) p[1] = decodeURIComponent(p[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        b[p[0]] = p[1];
    }
    return b;
})((url.split('?'))[1].split('&'));
```

**IMPORTANT!** The parameter for that function in the last line is different. It's just an example of how one can pass an arbitrary URL to it. You can use last line from Bruno's answer to parse the current URL.

So what exactly changed? With url `http://sb.com/reg/step1?param=` results will be same. But with url `http://sb.com/reg/step1?param` Bruno's solution returns an object without keys, while mine returns an object with key `param` and `undefined` value.

Answer (score 36):

I like [this one](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html) (taken from jquery-howto.blogspot.co.uk):

```
// get an array with all querystring values
// example: var valor = getUrlVars()["valor"];
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

Works great for me.

Answer (score 34):

Here's an extended version of Andy E's linked "Handle array-style query strings"-version. Fixed a bug (`?key=1&key[]=2&key[]=3`; `1` is lost and replaced with `[2,3]`), made a few minor performance improvements (re-decoding of values, recalculating "[" position, etc.) and added a number of improvements (functionalized, support for `?key=1&key=2`, support for `;` delimiters). I left the variables annoyingly short, but added comments galore to make them readable (oh, and I reused `v` within the local functions, sorry if that is confusing ;).

It will handle the following querystring...

> ?test=Hello&person=neek&person[]=jeff&person[]=jim&person[extra]=john&test3&nocache=1398914891264

...making it into an object that looks like...

```
{
    "test": "Hello",
    "person": {
        "0": "neek",
        "1": "jeff",
        "2": "jim",
        "length": 3,
        "extra": "john"
    },
    "test3": "",
    "nocache": "1398914891264"
}
```

As you can see above, this version handles some measure of "malformed" arrays, i.e. - `person=neek&person[]=jeff&person[]=jim` or `person=neek&person=jeff&person=jim` as the key is identifiable and valid (at least in dotNet's [NameValueCollection.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsc9a449.aspx)):

> If the specified key already exists in the target NameValueCollection
>   instance, the specified value is added to the existing comma-separated
>   list of values in the form "value1,value2,value3".

It seems [the jury is somewhat out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746507/authoritative-position-of-duplicate-http-get-query-keys) on repeated keys as there is no spec. In this case, multiple keys are stored as an (fake)array. But do note that I **do not** process values based on commas into arrays.

**The code:**

```
getQueryStringKey = function(key) {
    return getQueryStringAsObject()[key];
};


getQueryStringAsObject = function() {
    var b, cv, e, k, ma, sk, v, r = {},
        d = function (v) { return decodeURIComponent(v).replace(/\+/g, " "); }, //# d(ecode) the v(alue)
        q = window.location.search.substring(1), //# suggested: q = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
        s = /([^&;=]+)=?([^&;]*)/g //# original regex that does not allow for ; as a delimiter:   /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g
    ;

    //# ma(make array) out of the v(alue)
    ma = function(v) {
        //# If the passed v(alue) hasn't been setup as an object
        if (typeof v != "object") {
            //# Grab the cv(current value) then setup the v(alue) as an object
            cv = v;
            v = {};
            v.length = 0;

            //# If there was a cv(current value), .push it into the new v(alue)'s array
            //#     NOTE: This may or may not be 100% logical to do... but it's better than loosing the original value
            if (cv) { Array.prototype.push.call(v, cv); }
        }
        return v;
    };

    //# While we still have key-value e(ntries) from the q(uerystring) via the s(earch regex)...
    while (e = s.exec(q)) { //# while((e = s.exec(q)) !== null) {
        //# Collect the open b(racket) location (if any) then set the d(ecoded) v(alue) from the above split key-value e(ntry) 
        b = e[1].indexOf("[");
        v = d(e[2]);

        //# As long as this is NOT a hash[]-style key-value e(ntry)
        if (b < 0) { //# b == "-1"
            //# d(ecode) the simple k(ey)
            k = d(e[1]);

            //# If the k(ey) already exists
            if (r[k]) {
                //# ma(make array) out of the k(ey) then .push the v(alue) into the k(ey)'s array in the r(eturn value)
                r[k] = ma(r[k]);
                Array.prototype.push.call(r[k], v);
            }
            //# Else this is a new k(ey), so just add the k(ey)/v(alue) into the r(eturn value)
            else {
                r[k] = v;
            }
        }
        //# Else we've got ourselves a hash[]-style key-value e(ntry) 
        else {
            //# Collect the d(ecoded) k(ey) and the d(ecoded) sk(sub-key) based on the b(racket) locations
            k = d(e[1].slice(0, b));
            sk = d(e[1].slice(b + 1, e[1].indexOf("]", b)));

            //# ma(make array) out of the k(ey) 
            r[k] = ma(r[k]);

            //# If we have a sk(sub-key), plug the v(alue) into it
            if (sk) { r[k][sk] = v; }
            //# Else .push the v(alue) into the k(ey)'s array
            else { Array.prototype.push.call(r[k], v); }
        }
    }

    //# Return the r(eturn value)
    return r;
};
```

Comment: For getting the query string values you can use this "GetParameterValues" function.
In this you just have to pass the query stirng parameter name and it'll return you the value


$(document).ready(function () {
 var bid = GetParameterValues('token');
});

function GetParameterValues(param) {
    var url = decodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
    url = url.slice(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
        var urlparam = url[i].split('=');
        if (urlparam[0] == param) {
            return urlparam[1];
        }
}

Comment: I've been using this for a while now, and it's been great so far. Except for handling urlencoded arrays.  
Using `q = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),` helps it do that too.

Comment: for me this went on an endless loop if there were no query params :(

Answer (score 33):

I needed an object from the query string, and I hate lots of code. It may not be the most robust in the universe, but it's just a few lines of code.

```
var q = {};
location.href.split('?')[1].split('&').forEach(function(i){
    q[i.split('=')[0]]=i.split('=')[1];
});
```

A URL like `this.htm?hello=world&foo=bar` will create:

```
{hello:'world', foo:'bar'}
```

Comment: Neat. According to Mozilla, though, [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) doesn't work on IE7 or 8 and I suspect that'll fall over if there's no query string at all. One minimal improvement that would cover more cases would be to [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) the value as you store it - and arguably the key as well, but you're less likely to use odd strings in that.

Comment: Nice and simple. Doesn't handle array parameters nor `?a&b&c` but this is really very readable (and incidentally similar to my first idea). Also the `split` is redundant but I've got bigger performance fish to fry than splitting a 10 character string twice.

Comment: when querystring is "?hello=world&one=a=b&two=2" then when you grab the value of 'one' you only get the part before the first '=' in the value. its value shud be 'a=b' but you only get 'a' because you split 'one=a=b' on '='. this is simply buggy. :((

Answer (score 32):

This is a function I created a while back and I'm quite happy with. It is not case sensitive - which is handy. Also, if the requested QS doesn't exist, it just returns an empty string.

I use a compressed version of this. I'm posting uncompressed for the novice types to better explain what's going on.

I'm sure this could be optimized or done differently to work faster, but it's always worked great for what I need.

Enjoy.

```
function getQSP(sName, sURL) {
    var theItmToRtn = "";
    var theSrchStrg = location.search;
    if (sURL) theSrchStrg = sURL;
    var sOrig = theSrchStrg;
    theSrchStrg = theSrchStrg.toUpperCase();
    sName = sName.toUpperCase();
    theSrchStrg = theSrchStrg.replace("?", "&") theSrchStrg = theSrchStrg + "&";
    var theSrchToken = "&" + sName + "=";
    if (theSrchStrg.indexOf(theSrchToken) != -1) {
        var theSrchTokenLth = theSrchToken.length;
        var theSrchTokenLocStart = theSrchStrg.indexOf(theSrchToken) + theSrchTokenLth;
        var theLocOfNextAndSign = theSrchStrg.indexOf("&", theSrchTokenLocStart);
        theItmToRtn = unescape(sOrig.substring(theSrchTokenLocStart, theLocOfNextAndSign));
    }
    return unescape(theItmToRtn);
}
```

Comment: Also, better to go for decodeURI() or decodeURIComponent() instead of unescape().

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape

Answer (score 31):

```
function GetQueryStringParams(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');

    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++)
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam)
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}​
```

And this is how you can use this function assuming the URL is

> `http://example.com/?stringtext=jquery&stringword=jquerybyexample`

```
var tech = GetQueryStringParams('stringtext');
var blog = GetQueryStringParams('stringword');
```

Comment: There's a few implementations of this approach here already. At the very least you need to decodeUriComponent() the result values. This might also misbehave if you don't specify a value, e.g. `?stringtext&stringword=foo`.

Answer (score 29):

If you are using Browserify, you can use the `url` module from *Node.js*:

```
var url = require('url');

url.parse('http://example.com/?bob=123', true).query;

// returns { "bob": "123" }
```

Further reading: [**URL Node.js v0.12.2 Manual & Documentation**](http://nodejs.org/api/url.html)

**EDIT:** You can use [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) interface, its quite widely adopted in almost all the new browser and if the code is going to run on an old browser you can use a [polyfill like this one](https://github.com/lifaon74/url-polyfill). Here's a code example on how to use URL interface to get query parameters (aka search parameters)

```
const url = new URL('http://example.com/?bob=123');
url.searchParams.get('bob');
```

You can also use URLSearchParams for it, here's [an example from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams#Example) to do it with URLSearchParams:

```
var paramsString = "q=URLUtils.searchParams&topic=api";
var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(paramsString);

//Iterate the search parameters.
for (let p of searchParams) {
  console.log(p);
}

searchParams.has("topic") === true; // true
searchParams.get("topic") === "api"; // true
searchParams.getAll("topic"); // ["api"]
searchParams.get("foo") === null; // true
searchParams.append("topic", "webdev");
searchParams.toString(); // "q=URLUtils.searchParams&topic=api&topic=webdev"
searchParams.set("topic", "More webdev");
searchParams.toString(); // "q=URLUtils.searchParams&topic=More+webdev"
searchParams.delete("topic");
searchParams.toString(); // "q=URLUtils.searchParams"
```

Comment: The documentation for the `url` module's API is here: http://nodejs.org/api/url.html

Comment: This is nice for nw.js development. Browserify isn't even needed as most node modules work as is in a nw.js window. I've tested this code and works like a charm without any modification.

Comment: OHH this is awesome! URLSearchParams works perfect. Many thanks!

Comment: should probably be the best voted, no hassle with custom functions and additional libraries. It also seems to be mostly adopted by the browsers 2019.

Answer (score 27):

The problem with the top answer on that question is that it's not-supported parameters placed after #, but sometimes it's needed to get this value also.

I modified the answer to let it parse a full query string with a hash sign also:

```
var getQueryStringData = function(name) {
    var result = null;
    var regexS = "[\\?&#]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
    var results = regex.exec('?' + window.location.href.split('?')[1]);
    if (results != null) {
        result = decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    return result;
};
```

Comment: That's interesting if you need it but there's no standard for the format of the hash part AFAIK so it's not fair to call that out as a weakness of the other answer.

Comment: Yes, I know. But in my app i integrate 3rd party js navigation, which have some parameters after hash sign.

Comment: For example, in the Google search page, the searching query is followed by the hash sign '#'.

Answer (score 27):

We've just released [arg.js](https://github.com/stretchr/arg.js), a project aimed at solving this problem once and for all.  It's traditionally been so difficult but now you can do:

```
var name = Arg.get("name");
```

or getting the whole lot:

```
var params = Arg.all();
```

and if you care about the difference between `?query=true` and `#hash=true` then you can use the `Arg.query()` and `Arg.hash()` methods.

Comment: you saved me man.. arg.js is the solution none of the solutions is getting the values from # in IE 8..:(  any one searching for IE8 # get from request this is the solution..

Answer (score 25):

See it in Action: https://codepen.io/ajorpheus/pen/XWyWWNQ

---

```
http://someurl.com?key=value&keynovalue&keyemptyvalue=&&keynovalue=nowhasvalue#somehash
```

- Regular key/value pair (`?param=value`)
- Keys w/o value (`?param` : no equal sign or value)
- Keys w/ empty value (`?param=` : equal sign, but no value to right of equal sign)
- Repeated Keys (`?param=1&param=2`)
- Removes Empty Keys (`?&&` : no key or value)

###Code:

-

```
    var queryString = window.location.search || '';
    var keyValPairs = [];
    var params      = {};
    queryString     = queryString.substr(1);

    if (queryString.length)
    {
       keyValPairs = queryString.split('&');
       for (pairNum in keyValPairs)
       {
          var key = keyValPairs[pairNum].split('=')[0];
          if (!key.length) continue;
          if (typeof params[key] === 'undefined')
             params[key] = [];
          params[key].push(keyValPairs[pairNum].split('=')[1]);
       }
    }
```

###How to Call:

-

```
    params['key'];  // returns an array of values (1..n)
```

###Output:

-

```
    key            ["value"]
    keyemptyvalue  [""]
    keynovalue     [undefined, "nowhasvalue"]
```

Answer (score 23):

This one works fine. Regular expressions in some of the other answers introduce unnecessary overhead.

```
function getQuerystring(key) {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        if (pair[0] == key) {
            return pair[1];
        }
    }
}
```

taken from [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1771251.aspx/1)

Comment: You probably at least want to call [`decodeUriComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) on the `pair[1]` before you return it, if not replace pluses with spaces first as in all the other solutions here. Some of the other solutions also prefer a limit of 2 parts on the split `=` to be more lenient in accepting input.

Comment: @Rup you are right...actually in my code it'll always be a number rather than any special characters, so missed ...

Comment: Thanks for it! It's the only method supported by the Kindle's Experimental Browser. Freak project here! :·)

Answer (score 21):

I developed a small library using techniques listed here to create an easy to use, drop-in solution to anyones troubles; It can be found here:

https://github.com/Nijikokun/query-js

**Usage**

Fetching specific parameter/key:

```
query.get('param');
```

Using the builder to fetch the entire object:

```
var storage = query.build();
console.log(storage.param);
```

and tons more... check the github link for more examples.

**Features**

1. Caching on both decoding and parameters
2. Supports hash query strings `#hello?page=3`
3. Supports passing custom queries
4. Supports Array / Object Parameters `user[]="jim"&user[]="bob"`
5. Supports empty management `&&`
6. Supports declaration parameters without values `name&hello="world"`
7. Supports repeated parameters `param=1&param=2`
8. Clean, compact, and readable source `4kb`
9. AMD, Require, Node support

Answer (score 20):

One-liner to get the query:

```
var value = location.search.match(new RegExp(key + "=(.*?)($|\&)", "i"))[1];
```

Comment: Triggers error if the key doesn't exist, try this maybe?  `(location.search.match(new RegExp('kiosk_modeasdf' + "=(.*?)($|\&)", "i")) || [])[1]`

Comment: @Brad, of course it's undefined, since that's the key you're looking for. if your query is?hello=world, `var value = location.search.match(new RegExp("hello" + "=(.*?)($|\&)", "i"))[1];` will return `"world"`

Comment: @BradKoch I found your solution this best, especially with a short circuit to an empty string (window.location.search.match(new RegExp('kiosk_modeasdf' + "=(.*?)($|\&)", "i")) || [])[1] || '';

Comment: i think you forgot testing for key starting with either '?' or '&' like:
var result = location.search.match(new RegExp("[\?\&]" + key + "=(.*?)($|\&)", "i"));

Answer (score 18):

Here is [my version of query string parsing code on GitHub](https://github.com/voituk/Misc/blob/master/js/jquery.hash.js#L10).

It's "prefixed" with jquery.*, but the parsing function itself don't use jQuery. It's pretty fast, but still open for few simple performance optimizations.

Also it supports list & hash-tables encoding in the URL, like:

```
arr[]=10&arr[]=20&arr[]=100
```

or

```
hash[key1]=hello&hash[key2]=moto&a=How%20are%20you
```

---

```
jQuery.toQueryParams = function(str, separator) {
    separator = separator || '&'
    var obj = {}
    if (str.length == 0)
        return obj
    var c = str.substr(0,1)
    var s = c=='?' || c=='#'  ? str.substr(1) : str; 

    var a = s.split(separator)
    for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
        var p = a[i].indexOf('=')
        if (p < 0) {
            obj[a[i]] = ''
            continue
        }
        var k = decodeURIComponent(a[i].substr(0,p)),
            v = decodeURIComponent(a[i].substr(p+1))

        var bps = k.indexOf('[')
        if (bps < 0) {
            obj[k] = v
            continue;
        } 

        var bpe = k.substr(bps+1).indexOf(']')
        if (bpe < 0) {
            obj[k] = v
            continue;
        }

        var bpv = k.substr(bps+1, bps+bpe-1)
        var k = k.substr(0,bps)
        if (bpv.length <= 0) {
            if (typeof(obj[k]) != 'object') obj[k] = []
            obj[k].push(v)
        } else {
            if (typeof(obj[k]) != 'object') obj[k] = {}
            obj[k][bpv] = v
        }
    }
    return obj;

}
```

Comment: nice but doesnt deal with the case `filters[topic][]=list`

Comment: Hey, how to use the above code to get value by Key?? I want to get city values from this URL...
http://abc.xyzl/urlpart1/urlpart2?city%5B0%5D=55&page=2&city[]=4&functionalarea[]=1&functionalarea[]=2

Answer (score 18):

I would rather use `split()` instead of Regex for this operation:

```
function getUrlParams() {
    var result = {};
    var params = (window.location.search.split('?')[1] || '').split('&');
    for(var param in params) {
        if (params.hasOwnProperty(param)) {
            var paramParts = params[param].split('=');
            result[paramParts[0]] = decodeURIComponent(paramParts[1] || "");
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I wasn't wanting to use Regex and went with this solution.  I find it works rather nicely.  Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

A very lightweight jQuery method:

```
var qs = window.location.search.replace('?','').split('&'),
    request = {};
$.each(qs, function(i,v) {
    var initial, pair = v.split('=');
    if(initial = request[pair[0]]){
        if(!$.isArray(initial)) {
            request[pair[0]] = [initial]
        }
        request[pair[0]].push(pair[1]);
    } else {
        request[pair[0]] = pair[1];
    }
    return;
});
console.log(request);
```

And to alert, for example ?q

```
alert(request.q)
```

Comment: Neat. There's a few answers in the same vein already - iterating over a split - albeit none using jQuery's each, and I don't think any of them are perfect yet either. I don't understand the `return` in your closure though, and I think you need to `decodeUriComponent` the two `pair[]` values as you read them.

Comment: yea having the decodeUriComponent is def best practice- i just kinda wrote that on the fly. As for the return... i just stay in the habit of returning something. totally not necessary

Answer (score 13):

Here's what I'm using:

```
/**
 * Examples:
 * getUrlParams()['myparam']    // url defaults to the current page
 * getUrlParams(url)['myparam'] // url can be just a query string
 *
 * Results of calling `getUrlParams(url)['myparam']` with various urls:
 * example.com                               (undefined)
 * example.com?                              (undefined)
 * example.com?myparam                       (empty string)
 * example.com?myparam=                      (empty string)
 * example.com?myparam=0                     (the string '0')
 * example.com?myparam=0&myparam=override    (the string 'override')
 *
 * Origin: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23946023/2407309
 */
function getUrlParams (url) {
    var urlParams = {} // return value
    var queryString = getQueryString()
    if (queryString) {
        var keyValuePairs = queryString.split('&')
        for (var i = 0; i < keyValuePairs.length; i++) {
            var keyValuePair = keyValuePairs[i].split('=')
            var paramName = keyValuePair[0]
            var paramValue = keyValuePair[1] || ''
            urlParams[paramName] = decodeURIComponent(paramValue.replace(/\+/g, ' '))
        }
    }
    return urlParams // functions below
    function getQueryString () {
        var reducedUrl = url || window.location.search
        reducedUrl = reducedUrl.split('#')[0] // Discard fragment identifier.
        var queryString = reducedUrl.split('?')[1]
        if (!queryString) {
            if (reducedUrl.search('=') !== false) { // URL is a query string.
                queryString = reducedUrl
            }
        }
        return queryString
    } // getQueryString
} // getUrlParams
```

Returning 'override' rather than '0' in the last case makes it consistent with PHP. Works in IE7.

Comment: That's because everyone seems to have different requirements for handling keys without values or handling duplicated keys by building arrays of values, etc. There are plenty of split answers already but I don't see one that does exactly the same as this one, true. (FWIW I think `paramName` needs to be `decodeURIComponent`ed too technically, though I doubt anyone would use non-trivial params.)

Comment: Parameter names should never need decoding.

Comment: Why not? [HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#naming-form-controls:-the-name-attribute) doesn't restrict the character set for input control names, nor is there any guarantee that they come from HTML anyway. I can't see why there would be a restriction to printable characters.

Comment: The solution is good, but why no semicolon at the end of statements?

Comment: @Sudar Because there is no reason to have them. Most people always include them just because they've always seen other people include them and because other languages require them; often they are wrongly regarded as required in JavaScript as well, which sometimes causes baffling problems. Doing things for no reason is generally misleading; JavaScript is not C++ or PHP. Look up `defensive semicolon`.

Answer (score 10):

**Get all querystring parameters including checkbox values (arrays).**

Considering the correct & normal use of GET parameters, the things I see it's missing, on most functions, is the support for arrays and removing the hash data.

So I wrote this function:

```
function qs(a){
 if(!a)return {};
 a=a.split('#')[0].split('&');
 var b=a.length,c={},d,k,v;
 while(b--){
  d=a[b].split('=');
  k=d[0].replace('[]',''),v=decodeURIComponent(d[1]||'');
  c[k]?typeof c[k]==='string'?(c[k]=[v,c[k]]):(c[k].unshift(v)):c[k]=v;
 }
 return c
}
```

Using shorthand operators & while-- loop, the performance should be very good to.

**Support:**

1. Empty values (*key= / key*)
2. Key value (*key=value*)
3. Arrays (*key[]=value*)
4. Hash (*the hash tag is split out*)

**Notes:**

It does not support object arrays (key[key]=value)

If the space is + it remains a +.

Add `.replace(/\+/g, " ")` if you need.

**Usage:**

```
qs('array[]=1&array[]=2&key=value&empty=&empty2#hash')
```

**Return:**

```
{
    "empty": "",
    "key": "value",
    "array": [
        "1",
        "2"
    ]
}
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/ZQMrt/1/

**Info**

If you don't understand something or you can't read the function just ask. I'm happy to explain what I did here.

*If you think the function is unreadable and unmaintainable I'm happy to rewrite the function for you, but consider that shorthand & bitwise operators are always faster than a standard syntax (maybe read about shorthands and bitwise operators in the ECMA-262 book or use your favorite search engine). Rewriting the code in a standard readable syntax means performance loss.*

Comment: Very neat, though I find it hard to believe that writing it pre-minified actually helps anything but the first parse, or helps in general if people are going to minify their production code anyway. Most of the functions here don't need to strip the hash-part because they start with `location.search` which doesn't contain it. I'm also not clear what you mean "bitwise operators" - you're using empty-or-undefined-is-false in a couple of places which is as close as you get but there's no bit manipulation here.

Comment: If you use arrays for more than checkbox values, add:       if ( v.charAt(0) == '[' ) {
        v = v.replace('[', '["').replace(']', '"]').replace(',', '","');
        v = JSON && JSON.parse(v) || $.parseJSON(v);
      } before "c[k]?typeof ..."

Comment: I need one that supports object arrays

Answer (score 10):

For those who wants a short method (with limitations):

```
location.search.split('myParameter=')[1]
```

Comment: That's not enough for the general case: it assumes 1) that you're only interested in a single parameter 2) that it's guaranteed to be the last parameter in the line (i.e. you can guarantee that all browsers will put it last, or it's the only param on the page, and that you're not going to e.g. put the URL in an RSS feed aggregator where it might get utm parameters added) and 3) that there are no characters in the value that can be escaped for transmission, e.g. spaces or many symbols.

Comment: There's no 1 size fits all methods. If you have a perfect solution in a one-short-liner, I'll be all eyes and ears to check that out. Above is a quick solution, not for general case, but for coders who want a light weight and quick solution to static implementations. In any case, thanks for your comment.

Comment: (location.search.split('myParameter=')[1]).split('&')[0] ;
this gives you the same result in case of multiple parameters. Still useful only for static implementations.

Answer (score 9):

```
function getUrlVar(key){
    var result = new RegExp(key + "=([^&]*)", "i").exec(window.location.search); 
    return result && unescape(result[1]) || ""; 
}
```

https://gist.github.com/1771618

Answer (score 8):

The following code will create an object which has two methods:

1. `isKeyExist`: Check if a particular parameter exist
2. `getValue`: Get the value of a particular parameter.

```
var QSParam = new function() {
       var qsParm = {};
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var params = query.split('&');
       for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
           var pos = params[i].indexOf('=');
           if (pos > 0) {
               var key = params[i].substring(0, pos);
               var val = params[i].substring(pos + 1);
               qsParm[key] = val;
           }
       }
       this.isKeyExist = function(query){
           if(qsParm[query]){
               return true;
           }
           else{
              return false;
           }
       };
       this.getValue = function(query){
           if(qsParm[query])
           {
               return qsParm[query];
           }
           throw "URL does not contain query "+ query;
       }
};
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
String.prototype.getValueByKey = function(k){
    var p = new RegExp('\\b'+k+'\\b','gi');
    return this.search(p) != -1 ? decodeURIComponent(this.substr(this.search(p)+k.length+1).substr(0,this.substr(this.search(p)+k.length+1).search(/(&|;|$)/))) : "";
};
```

Then call it like so:

```
if(location.search != "") location.search.getValueByKey("id");
```

You can use this for **cookies** also:

```
if(navigator.cookieEnabled) document.cookie.getValueByKey("username");
```

This only works for strings that have `key=value[&|;|$]`... will not work on objects/arrays.

If you **don't** want to use **String.prototype**...
move it to a function and pass the string as an argument

Answer (score 7):

Here's my own take on this. This first function decodes a URL string into an object of name/value pairs:

```
url_args_decode = function (url) {
  var args_enc, el, i, nameval, ret;
  ret = {};
  // use the DOM to parse the URL via an 'a' element
  el = document.createElement("a");
  el.href = url;
  // strip off initial ? on search and split
  args_enc = el.search.substring(1).split('&');
  for (i = 0; i < args_enc.length; i++) {
    // convert + into space, split on =, and then decode 
    args_enc[i].replace(/\+/g, ' ');
    nameval = args_enc[i].split('=', 2);
    ret[decodeURIComponent(nameval[0])]=decodeURIComponent(nameval[1]);
  }
  return ret;
};
```

And as an added bonus, if you change some of the args, you can use this second function to put the array of args back into the URL string:

```
url_args_replace = function (url, args) {
  var args_enc, el, name;
  // use the DOM to parse the URL via an 'a' element
  el = document.createElement("a");
  el.href = url;
  args_enc = [];
  // encode args to go into url
  for (name in args) {
    if (args.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      name = encodeURIComponent(name);
      args[name] = encodeURIComponent(args[name]);
      args_enc.push(name + '=' + args[name]);
    }
  }
  if (args_enc.length > 0) {
    el.search = '?' + args_enc.join('&');
  } else {
    el.search = '';
  }
  return el.href;
};
```

Comment: If your anyway using the jQuery, Then the later method (`url_args_replace`) can be used via `$.param()`

Comment: Why do you use document.createElement("a") ?

Comment: @greg to create the element in the browser engine, which will parse a url for you and provide search and href methods for interacting with the url string.

Answer (score 7):

I used this code (JavaScript) to get the what is passed through the URL:

```
function getUrlVars() {
            var vars = {};
            var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
                vars[key] = value;
            });
            return vars;
        }
```

Then to assign the value to a variable, you only have to specify which parameter you want to get, ie if the URL is `example.com/?I=1&p=2&f=3`

You can do this to get the values:

```
var getI = getUrlVars()["I"];
var getP = getUrlVars()["p"];
var getF = getUrlVars()["f"];
```

then the values would be:

```
getI = 1, getP = 2 and getF = 3
```

Comment: That's neat, although it's missing `decodeURIComponent` on the key and the value and you probably don't need the `i` flag on the regexp (not that that really matters).

Comment: but what if you have example.com/3 (MVC routing)

Answer (score 6):

The following function returns an object version of your queryString. 
You can simply write `obj.key1` and  `obj.key2` to access values of `key1` and `key2` in parameter.

```
function getQueryStringObject()
{
    var querystring = document.location.search.replace('?','').split( '&' );
    var objQueryString={};
    var key="",val="";
    if(typeof querystring == 'undefined')
    {
        return (typeof querystring);
    }
    for(i=0;i<querystring.length;i++)
    {
        key=querystring[i].split("=")[0];
        val=querystring[i].split("=")[1];
        objQueryString[key] = val;
    }
    return objQueryString;
}
```

And to use this function you can write

```
var obj= getQueryStringObject();
alert(obj.key1);
```

Answer (score 6):

This function converts the querystring to a JSON-like object, it also handles value-less and multi-value parameters:

```js
"use strict";
function getQuerystringData(name) {
    var data = { };
    var parameters = window.location.search.substring(1).split("&");
    for (var i = 0, j = parameters.length; i < j; i++) {
        var parameter = parameters[i].split("=");
        var parameterName = decodeURIComponent(parameter[0]);
        var parameterValue = typeof parameter[1] === "undefined" ? parameter[1] : decodeURIComponent(parameter[1]);
        var dataType = typeof data[parameterName];
        if (dataType === "undefined") {
            data[parameterName] = parameterValue;
        } else if (dataType === "array") {
            data[parameterName].push(parameterValue);
        } else {
            data[parameterName] = [data[parameterName]];
            data[parameterName].push(parameterValue);
        }
    }
    return typeof name === "string" ? data[name] : data;
}
```

We perform a check for `undefined` on `parameter[1]` because `decodeURIComponent` returns the string "undefined" if the variable is `undefined`, and that's wrong.

Usage:

```js
"use strict";
var data = getQuerystringData();
var parameterValue = getQuerystringData("parameterName");
```

Answer (score 6):

I did a small URL library for my needs here: https://github.com/Mikhus/jsurl

It's a more common way of manipulating the URLs in JavaScript. Meanwhile it's really lightweight (minified and gzipped < 1 KB) and has a very simple and clean API. And it does not need any other library to work.

Regarding the initial question, it's very simple to do:

```
var u = new Url; // Current document URL
// or
var u = new Url('http://user:pass@example.com:8080/some/path?foo=bar&bar=baz#anchor');

// Looking for query string parameters
alert( u.query.bar);
alert( u.query.foo);

// Modifying query string parameters
u.query.foo = 'bla';
u.query.woo = ['hi', 'hey']

alert(u.query.foo);
alert(u.query.woo);
alert(u);
```

Comment: That's interesting. Why decode the value manually? You'll also limited in the top character code you can accept as UTF-8, although I realise you're unlikely to ever hit that in practice.

Comment: Why decoding in that way explained here: http://unixpapa.com/js/querystring.html Actually, I've took the code for that idea from there, what is stated in a top-level comment at my script

Comment: also doesnt't support object arrays like `filters[topic][]=list`

Answer (score 5):

I took [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-values-in-javascript/3855394#3855394) and added support for optionally passing the URL in as a parameter; falls back to window.location.search. Obviously this is useful for getting the query string parameters from URLs that are not the current page:

```
(function($, undef) {
  $.QueryString = function(url) {
    var pairs, qs = null, index, map = {};
    if(url == undef){
      qs = window.location.search.substr(1);
    }else{
      index = url.indexOf('?');
      if(index == -1) return {};
      qs = url.substring(index+1);
    }
    pairs = qs.split('&');
    if (pairs == "") return {};
    for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; ++i)
    {
      var p = pairs[i].split('=');
      if(p.length != 2) continue;
      map[p[0]] = decodeURIComponent(p[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    return map;
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have [Underscore.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underscore.js) or [lodash](http://lodash.com/docs#zipObject), a quick and dirty way to get this done is:

```
_.object(window.location.search.slice(1).split('&').map(function (val) { return val.split('='); }));
```

Comment: Neat. Compared to the [top split-based answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3855394) though you're missing handling of +s and the decodeURIComponent calls, but for simple values this will be enough.

Comment: Yeah, it's really just meant for grabbing simple alphanumeric tokens. In a current project, it's all I needed, so I didn't really want a hulking function.

Comment: this is what I use to make a key value object of the query parameters: `_.chain(document.location.search.slice(1).split('&')).invoke('split', '=').object().value()`

Answer (score 4):

There is a nice little `url` utility for this with some cool sugaring:

```
http://www.example.com/path/index.html?silly=willy#chucky=cheese

url();            // http://www.example.com/path/index.html?silly=willy#chucky=cheese
url('domain');    // example.com
url('1');         // path
url('-1');        // index.html
url('?');         // silly=willy
url('?silly');    // willy
url('?poo');      // (an empty string)
url('#');         // chucky=cheese
url('#chucky');   // cheese
url('#poo');      // (an empty string)
```

Check out more examples and download here: https://github.com/websanova/js-url#url

Answer (score 4):

***This the most simple and small function JavaScript to get int ans String parameter value from URL***

```
/* THIS FUNCTION IS TO FETCH INT PARAMETER VALUES */

function getParameterint(param) {
            var val = document.URL;
            var url = val.substr(val.indexOf(param))  
            var n=parseInt(url.replace(param+"=",""));
            alert(n); 
}
getParameteraint("page");
getParameteraint("pagee");

/*THIS FUNCTION IS TO FETCH STRING PARAMETER*/
function getParameterstr(param) {
            var val = document.URL;
            var url = val.substr(val.indexOf(param))  
            var n=url.replace(param+"=","");
            alert(n); 
}
getParameterstr("str");
```

**Source And DEMO :** http://bloggerplugnplay.blogspot.in/2012/08/how-to-get-url-parameter-in-javascript.html

Comment: I think that can be easily defeated e.g. `?xyz=page&str=Expected&page=123` won't return 123 because it picks up the `page` string from `xyz=page`, and `str` will return `Expected&page=123` rather than just `Expected` if it's not the last value on the line, etc. You're also not decodeUriComponent-ing the values extracted. Plus I couldn't try your demo - I got redirected to a betting website??

Comment: @Rup you are talking about a RARE/WORST case.. But in normal and regular cases this code works fine and solves the purpose ...And about DEMO its working fine and shows how this function works! Thanks !

Comment: OK, finally managed to get your demo through adfly. Yes, that works OK but only because you have just the one string parameter and it's last - try using more than one and switching the orders around. Try putting the pagee parameter before the page parameter and it'll fail. For example here's [your demo with the order of the three reversed](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ipsjolly/T83ke/10/show/?str=Display&pagee=66&page=55). The other problem is if someone posts a string with a non-ASCII character in it, e.g. a space - it'll get URI encoded and you're not decoding that afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this to be an accurate and concise way to achieve this (modified from http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-variables/):

```js
function getQueryVariable(variable) {

    var query = window.location.search.substring(1),            // Remove the ? from the query string.
        vars = query.split("&");                                // Split all values by ampersand.

    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {                     // Loop through them...
        var pair = vars[i].split("=");                          // Split the name from the value.
        if (pair[0] == variable) {                              // Once the requested value is found...
            return ( pair[1] == undefined ) ? null : pair[1];   // Return null if there is no value (no equals sign), otherwise return the value.
        }
    }

    return undefined;                                           // Wasn't found.

}
```

Comment: That looks reasonable! You probably need to decode the values taken from the query string in case they've been encoded for submission with %s or +s though.

Answer (score 4):

If you want array-style parameters [URL.js](https://github.com/kevincox/url.js) supports arbitrarily nested array-style parameters as well as string indexes (maps). It also handles URL decoding.

```
url.get("val[0]=zero&val[1]=one&val[2]&val[3]=&val[4]=four&val[5][0]=n1&val[5][1]=n2&val[5][2]=n3&key=val", {array:true});
// Result
{
    val: [
        'zero',
        'one',
        true,
        '',
        'four',
        [ 'n1', 'n2', 'n3' ]
    ]
    key: 'val'
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you do not wish to use a JavaScript library you can use the JavaScript string functions to parse `window.location`. Keep this code in an external .js file and you can use it over and over again in different projects.

```
// Example - window.location = "index.htm?name=bob";

var value = getParameterValue("name");

alert("name = " + value);

function getParameterValue(param)
{
    var url = window.location;
    var parts = url.split('?');
    var params = parts[1].split('&');
    var val = "";

    for ( var i=0; i<params.length; i++)
    {
        var paramNameVal = params[i].split('=');

        if ( paramNameVal[0] == param )
        {
            val = paramNameVal[1];
        }
    }
    return val;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a robust implementation in Node.js's source
https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/querystring.js

Also TJ's qs does nested params parsing
https://github.com/visionmedia/node-querystring

Answer (score 4):

```
var getUrlParameters = function (name, url) {
    if (!name) {
        return undefined;
    }

    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
    url = url || location.search;

    var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&#]' + name + '=?([^&#]*)', 'gi'), result, resultList = [];

    while (result = regex.exec(url)) {
        resultList.push(decodeURIComponent(result[1].replace(/\+/g, ' ')));
    }

    return resultList.length ? resultList.length === 1 ? resultList[0] : resultList : undefined;
};
```

Comment: this is a lot better than accepted solution to handle array values in query string. i.e. arr[]=1&arr[]=2

Answer (score 4):

There are many solutions to retrieve URI query values, I prefer this one because it's short and works great:

```
function get(name){
   if(name=(new RegExp('[?&]'+encodeURIComponent(name)+'=([^&]*)')).exec(location.search))
      return decodeURIComponent(name[1]);
}
```

Comment: That's neat, although that's essentially the [top accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/) distilled down a bit, e.g. you've lost the decoding of pluses-for-spaces in values . The `encodeURIComponent` for the key name is new, though, and on one hand more correct than the accepted answer for considering encodings in the key but on the other will still miss non-minimal encodings, e.g. `get("key")` won't match `?k%65y=value`.

Answer (score 4):

This is very simple method to get parameter value(query string)

Use `gV(para_name)` function to retrieve its value

```
var a=window.location.search;
a=a.replace(a.charAt(0),""); //Removes '?'
a=a.split("&");

function gV(x){
 for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
  var b=a[i].substr(0,a[i].indexOf("="));
  if(x==b){
   return a[i].substr(a[i].indexOf("=")+1,a[i].length)}
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution with plain JavaScript and [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

```
alert(getQueryString("p2"));

function getQueryString (Param) {
    return decodeURI("http://www.example.com/?p1=p11&p2=p2222".replace(new RegExp("^(?:.*[&?]" + encodeURI(Param).replace(/[.+*]/g, "$&") + "(?:=([^&]*))?)?.*$", "i"), "$1"));
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QeLF3/)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend [Dar Lessons](http://www.darlesson.com/jquery/querystring/) as a good plugin. I have worked with it fo  a long time. You can also use the following code.
Jus put `var queryObj = {};` before document.ready and put the bellow code in the beginning of document.ready. After this code you can use `queryObj["queryObjectName"]` for any query object you have

```
var querystring = location.search.replace('?', '').split('&');
for (var i = 0; i < querystring.length; i++) {
    var name = querystring[i].split('=')[0];
    var value = querystring[i].split('=')[1];
    queryObj[name] = value;
}
```

Comment: Two plugs for Dar Lessons in two posts? I don't think we can recommend the current version at least: it's vulnerable to script injection attacks. (I've emailed him to let him know). Like a lot of the `split('=')` solutions here already you're missing `decodeURIComponent`, and you might also want to handle missing values more gracefully too.

Comment: Dar Lessons has now released 1.1 which fixes the script injection attack.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      var urlParams = {};
      (function () {
          var match,
          pl = /\+/g, // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
              search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
              decode = function (s) {
                  return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, " "));
              },
              query = window.location.search.substring(1);

          while (match = search.exec(query))
              urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
      })();
      if (urlParams["q1"] === 1) {
          return 1;
      }
```

Please check and let me know your comments. Also refer to *[How to get querystring value using jQuery](http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-to-get-querystring-value-using.html)*.

Comment: That's identical to [Soheil's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17567046/243245) which is itself a copy of [Andy E's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2880929/243245) wrapped in jQuery and with the check on the end. You've also copied Soheil's mistake in the last section: there's no way that `urlParams["q1"]` can `=== 1` since it will always be a string not an integer at that point, and also `return 1` from `$(document).ready()` doesn't really make sense either. Where did you get this code from?

Comment: @Rup : I have got this from http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/529496/Handling-QueryString-Using-jQuery

Answer (score 3):

Most pretty but basic:

```
data = {};
$.each(
    location.search.substr(1).split('&').filter(Boolean).map(function(kvpairs){
        return kvpairs.split('=')
    }),
    function(i,values) {
        data[values.shift()] = values.join('=')
    }
);
```

It doesn't handle values lists such as `?a[]=1&a[]2`

Comment: Neat! You may need to trim the leading '?' off the first item (I don't know if that's always necessary, but many answers here do) and you need to perform some unescaping of the value too (`decodeURIComponent`, plusses-to-spaces)

Comment: Thank you, absolutely, and we also need a .filter(Boolean) to remove an empty string item in list when location.search is empty. That is:

`location.search.substr(1).split('&').filter(Boolean).map(...`

Comment: And the reverse: a query string from the returned hashmap:
`$.map(queryhash, function(v,k){ return [k,v].join('=')}).join('&')`

Answer (score 2):

See this [post](http://www.darlesson.com/jquery/querystring/) or use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var urlParams = {};
        (function ()
        {
            var match,
            pl= /\+/g,  // Regular expression for replacing addition symbol with a space
            search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
            decode = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, " ")); },
            query  = window.location.search.substring(1);

            while (match = search.exec(query))
                urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
        })();

        if (urlParams["q1"] === 1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Your sample usage - returning from a document ready - seems odd, and AFAICS it'll never work: `decode()` will only ever return a string and your triple-equals-comparing it to an integer. Otherwise seems a neat solution.

Comment: ... although it's the same as [Andy E's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2880929) above.

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

Doing this reliably is more involved than one may think at first.

1. `location.search`, which is used in other answers, is brittle and should be avoided - for example, it returns empty if someone screws up and puts a `#fragment` identifier before the `?query` string.
2. There are a number of ways URLs get automatically escaped in the browser, which makes `decodeURIComponent` pretty much mandatory, in my opinion.
3. Many query strings are generated from user input, which means assumptions about the URL content are very bad. Including very basic things like that each key is unique or even has a value.

To solve this, here is a configurable API with a healthy dose of [defensive programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming). Note that it can be made half the size if you are willing to hardcode some of the variables, or if the input can never include `hasOwnProperty`, etc.

**Version 1:** Returns a data object with names and values for each parameter. It effectively de-duplicates them and always respects the first one found from left-to-right.

```
function getQueryData(url, paramKey, pairKey, missingValue, decode) {

    var query, queryStart, fragStart, pairKeyStart, i, len, name, value, result;

    if (!url || typeof url !== 'string') {
        url = location.href; // more robust than location.search, which is flaky
    }
    if (!paramKey || typeof paramKey !== 'string') {
        paramKey = '&';
    }
    if (!pairKey || typeof pairKey !== 'string') {
        pairKey = '=';
    }
    // when you do not explicitly tell the API...
    if (arguments.length < 5) {
        // it will unescape parameter keys and values by default...
        decode = true;
    }

    queryStart = url.indexOf('?');
    if (queryStart >= 0) {
        // grab everything after the very first ? question mark...
        query = url.substring(queryStart + 1);
    } else {
        // assume the input is already parameter data...
        query = url;
    }
    // remove fragment identifiers...
    fragStart = query.indexOf('#');
    if (fragStart >= 0) {
        // remove everything after the first # hash mark...
        query = query.substring(0, fragStart);
    }
    // make sure at this point we have enough material to do something useful...
    if (query.indexOf(paramKey) >= 0 || query.indexOf(pairKey) >= 0) {
        // we no longer need the whole query, so get the parameters...
        query = query.split(paramKey);
        result = {};
        // loop through the parameters...
        for (i = 0, len = query.length; i < len; i = i + 1) {
            pairKeyStart = query[i].indexOf(pairKey);
            if (pairKeyStart >= 0) {
                name = query[i].substring(0, pairKeyStart);
            } else {
                name = query[i];
            }
            // only continue for non-empty names that we have not seen before...
            if (name && !Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(result, name)) {
                if (decode) {
                    // unescape characters with special meaning like ? and #
                    name = decodeURIComponent(name);
                }
                if (pairKeyStart >= 0) {
                    value = query[i].substring(pairKeyStart + 1);
                    if (value) {
                        if (decode) {
                            value = decodeURIComponent(value);
                        }
                    } else {
                        value = missingValue;
                    }
                } else {
                    value = missingValue;
                }
                result[name] = value;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Version 2:** Returns a data map object with two identical length arrays, one for names and one for values, with an index for each parameter. This one supports duplicate names and intentionally does not de-duplicate them, because that is probably why you would want to use this format.

```js
function getQueryData(url, paramKey, pairKey, missingValue, decode) {

    var query, queryStart, fragStart, pairKeyStart, i, len, name, value, result;

    if (!url || typeof url !== 'string') {
          url = location.href; // more robust than location.search, which is flaky
    }
        if (!paramKey || typeof paramKey !== 'string') {
            paramKey = '&';
        }
        if (!pairKey || typeof pairKey !== 'string') {
            pairKey = '=';
        }
        // when you do not explicitly tell the API...
        if (arguments.length < 5) {
            // it will unescape parameter keys and values by default...
            decode = true;
        }

        queryStart = url.indexOf('?');
        if (queryStart >= 0) {
            // grab everything after the very first ? question mark...
            query = url.substring(queryStart + 1);
        } else {
            // assume the input is already parameter data...
            query = url;
        }
        // remove fragment identifiers...
        fragStart = query.indexOf('#');
        if (fragStart >= 0) {
            // remove everything after the first # hash mark...
            query = query.substring(0, fragStart);
        }
        // make sure at this point we have enough material to do something useful...
        if (query.indexOf(paramKey) >= 0 || query.indexOf(pairKey) >= 0) {
            // we no longer need the whole query, so get the parameters...
            query = query.split(paramKey);
            result = {
                names: [],
                values: []
            };
            // loop through the parameters...
            for (i = 0, len = query.length; i < len; i = i + 1) {
                pairKeyStart = query[i].indexOf(pairKey);
                if (pairKeyStart >= 0) {
                    name = query[i].substring(0, pairKeyStart);
                } else {
                    name = query[i];
                }
                // only continue for non-empty names...
                if (name) {
                    if (decode) {
                        // unescape characters with special meaning like ? and #
                        name = decodeURIComponent(name);
                    }
                    if (pairKeyStart >= 0) {
                        value = query[i].substring(pairKeyStart + 1);
                        if (value) {
                            if (decode) {
                                value = decodeURIComponent(value);
                            }
                        } else {
                            value = missingValue;
                        }
                    } else {
                        value = missingValue;
                    }
                    result.names.push(name);
                    result.values.push(value);
                }
           }
           return result;
       }
   }
```

Comment: Neat, though the majority of answers here deal with splitting up the query part into parameters rather than extracting it from an arbitrary URL. Most of them assume we're on the current page and so just use `location.search` to get the string you're extracting.

Comment: this is not the point of the question, we need to extract each pair of query parameters as key/value, supporting arrays, empty values, etc.. by the way, "?hello#haha" is not a good behavior, as the #haha usually refeers to an anchor which does not make part of the parameter "hello"

Comment: I took the very short and vague question to mean something very different than what everyone else did. It's now obvious to me what was meant, and I have updated my answer to include a significantly better design that is on par.

Answer (score 2):

This will parse variables **AND** arrays from a URL string. It uses neither *regex* or any external library.

```
function url2json(url) {
   var obj={};
   function arr_vals(arr){
      if (arr.indexOf(',') > 1){
         var vals = arr.slice(1, -1).split(',');
         var arr = [];
         for (var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++)
            arr[i]=vals[i];
         return arr;
      }
      else
         return arr.slice(1, -1);
   }
   function eval_var(avar){
      if (!avar[1])
          obj[avar[0]] = '';
      else
      if (avar[1].indexOf('[') == 0)
         obj[avar[0]] = arr_vals(avar[1]);
      else
         obj[avar[0]] = avar[1];
   }
   if (url.indexOf('?') > -1){
      var params = url.split('?')[1];
      if(params.indexOf('&') > 2){
         var vars = params.split('&');
         for (var i in vars)
            eval_var(vars[i].split('='));
      }
      else
         eval_var(params.split('='));
   }
   return obj;
}
```

Example:

```
var url = "http://www.x.com?luckyNums=[31,21,6]&name=John&favFoods=[pizza]&noVal"
console.log(url2json(url));
```

Output:

```
[object]
   noVal: ""
   favFoods: "pizza"
   name:     "John"
   luckyNums:
      0: "31"
      1: "21"
      2: "6"
```

Answer (score 2):

This didn't work for me, I want to match `?b` as the `b` parameter is present, and not match `?return` as the `r` parameter, here is [my solution](https://gist.github.com/Dorian/833b37d2c7b168b7e94c).

```
window.query_param = function(name) {
  var param_value, params;

  params = location.search.replace(/^\?/, '');
  params = _.map(params.split('&'), function(s) {
    return s.split('=');
  });

  param_value = _.select(params, function(s) {
    return s.first === name;
  })[0];

  if (param_value) {
    return decodeURIComponent(param_value[1] || '');
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};
```

Comment: Which answer here didn't work for you, with those problems? (That'd be worth a comment on the answer itself, and I'd be interested to know too.) As for your solution, that looks like it's just a string-split solution using underscore.js? You're missing a call to `decodeURIComponent` probably.

Comment: Nice catch, I added the `decodeURIComponent` (and a spec for it). The most upvoted answer (the 2600 points one for jolly) doesn't works as expected: doesn't returns `null` for non-found parameters, and doesn't detect `?b` for instance a present parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The shortest possible expression in terms of size to obtain a query object seems to be:

```
var params = {};
location.search.substr(1).replace(/([^&=]*)=([^&]*)&?/g,
  function () { params[decodeURIComponent(arguments[1])] = decodeURIComponent(arguments[2]); });
```

You can make use of the `A` element to parse a URI from a string into its `location`-like components (to get rid of `#...`, for example):

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = url;
// Parse a.search.substr(1)... as above
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is `String` prototype implementation:

```
String.prototype.getParam = function( str ){
    str = str.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp( "[\\?&]*"+str+"=([^&#]*)" );    
    var results = regex.exec( this );
    if( results == null ){
        return "";
    } else {
        return results[1];
    }
}
```

Example call:

```
var status = str.getParam("status")
```

`str` can be a query string or url

Comment: That's basically the same as the [top answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/901144) though, less some some of the unescaping, just put on the String.prototype.

Comment: @Rup This is useful for parsing any string query, not just in a URL. for example Oauth2 returns token response as a query string, this String prototype will be useful for parsing, most important is `[\\?&]*` instead of `[\\?&]` in RegExp, for parsing query string staring with new line

Answer (score 1):

This will work... You need to call this function where you need get the parameter by passing its name...

```
function getParameterByName(name)
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  alert(results[1]);
  if (results == null)
    return "";
  else
    return results[1];
}
```

Comment: That's almost identical to the [top regexp answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/243245) except you're matching the whole URL not just the query string part and you're not removing escapes in the result.

Answer (score 1):

Quick, easy, and fast:

**The function:**

```
function getUrlVar() {
    var result = {};
    var location = window.location.href.split('#');
    var parts = location[0].replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        result [key] = value;
    });
    return result;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var varRequest = getUrlVar()["theUrlVarName"];
```

Comment: That's similar to [the fourth answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2880929), albeit with less escaping and you don't accept `?key` only params like that does (though you don't see them anymore). I'm not sure you need the `i` on the regexp options, and you're working with the whole href not just the search part which seems odd but it ought not make a difference.

Comment: @Rup Hi, Thank you for your comment - I can't see the similarity... He use `decodeURIComponent` which will work great but if we try it with accent characters - in some cases it fails (FF mostly) My answer As you can see is simple and quick that will fit most of the programmers who need a quick solution for query string variable extraction. Adding the i (case insensitivity) is a bit more flexible but can be removed, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

This function will return a parsed JavaScript object with any arbitrarily nested values using recursion as necessary.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WZHm5/3/) example.

```
[
  '?a=a',
  '&b=a',
  '&b=b',
  '&c[]=a',
  '&c[]=b',
  '&d[a]=a',
  '&d[a]=x',
  '&e[a][]=a',
  '&e[a][]=b',
  '&f[a][b]=a',
  '&f[a][b]=x',
  '&g[a][b][]=a',
  '&g[a][b][]=b',
  '&h=%2B+%25',
  '&i[aa=b',
  '&i[]=b',
  '&j=',
  '&k',
  '&=l',
  '&abc=foo',
  '&def=%5Basf%5D',
  '&ghi=[j%3Dkl]',
  '&xy%3Dz=5',
  '&foo=b%3Dar',
  '&xy%5Bz=5'
].join('');
```

Given any of the above test examples.

```
var qs = function(a) {
  var b, c, e;
  b = {};
  c = function(d) {
    return d && decodeURIComponent(d.replace(/\+/g, " "));
  };
  e = function(f, g, h) {
    var i, j, k, l;
    h = h ? h : null;
    i = /(.+?)\[(.+?)?\](.+)?/g.exec(g);
    if (i) {
      [j, k, l] = [i[1], i[2], i[3]]
      if (k === void 0) {
        if (f[j] === void 0) {
          f[j] = [];
        }
        f[j].push(h);
      } else {
        if (typeof f[j] !== "object") {
          f[j] = {};
        }
        if (l) {
          e(f[j], k + l, h);
        } else {
          e(f[j], k, h);
        }
      }
    } else {
      if (f.hasOwnProperty(g)) {
        if (Array.isArray(f[g])) {
          f[g].push(h);
        } else {
          f[g] = [].concat.apply([f[g]], [h]);
        }
      } else {
        f[g] = h;
      }
      return f[g];
    }
  };
  a.replace(/^(\?|#)/, "").replace(/([^#&=?]+)?=?([^&=]+)?/g, function(m, n, o) {
    n && e(b, c(n), c(o));
  });
  return b;
};
```

Comment: Looks broadly good, but why pre-minify it? It's tricky to follow in places as-is; in particular you're doing a few nasty things around the right-square-bracket line. Also an input something like `c[xx=a&c[]=b` will crash it.

Comment: My intention wasn't to pre-minify it, rather I just suck at naming variables, so I didn't try to come up with better names. I reworked the code to accommodate your example inputs and respond appropriately. I also switched to using regex's instead of trying to slice strings (which as you pointed out didn't always work).

Answer (score 0):

```
// Parse query string
var params = {}, queryString = location.hash.substring(1),
    regex = /([^&=]+)=([^&]*)/g,
    m;
while (m = regex.exec(queryString)) {
    params[decodeURIComponent(m[1])] = decodeURIComponent(m[2]);
}
```

Comment: Uh, hash != querystring.