# window.location.search query as JSON

Tags: jquery, json, search, window.location

Is there a better way to convert a URL's location.search as an object? Maybe just more efficient or trimmed down? I'm using jQuery, but pure JS can work too.

```
var query = window.location.search.substring(1), queryPairs = query.split('&'), queryJSON = {};
$.each(queryPairs, function() { queryJSON[this.split('=')[0]] = this.split('=')[1]; });
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here's a pure JS function.  Parses the search part of the current URL and returns an object.  (It's a bit verbose for readability, mind.)

```
function searchToObject() {
  var pairs = window.location.search.substring(1).split("&"),
    obj = {},
    pair,
    i;

  for ( i in pairs ) {
    if ( pairs[i] === "" ) continue;

    pair = pairs[i].split("=");
    obj[ decodeURIComponent( pair[0] ) ] = decodeURIComponent( pair[1] );
  }

  return obj;
}
```

On a related note, you're not trying to store the single parameters in "a JSON" but in "an object".  ;)

Answer (score 36):

Please also note that there's an api to query/manipulate search params with: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

```
var params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
for (let p of params) {
  console.log(p);
}
```

Comment: Dude, this is the kind of solution I was looking for. Browser support seems to be great except IE. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Probably the shortest solution for simple cases:

```
location.search
  .slice(1)
  .split('&')
  .map(p => p.split('='))
  .reduce((obj, [key, value]) => ({ ...obj, [key]: value }), {});
```

Answer (score 13):

If you are using modern browser this produce the same result as accepted answer:

```js
function searchToObject(search) {
  return search.substring(1).split("&").reduce(function(result, value) {
    var parts = value.split('=');
    if (parts[0]) result[decodeURIComponent(parts[0])] = decodeURIComponent(parts[1]);
    return result;
  }, {})
}
```

Answer (score 5):

My approach, simple and clean

```js
var params = "?q=Hello World&c=Awesome";

params = "{\"" + 
         params
         .replace( /\?/gi, "" )
         .replace( /\&/gi, "\",\"" )
         .replace( /\=/gi, "\":\"" ) +
         "\"}";
  
params = JSON.parse( params );

alert( decodeURIComponent( params.q ) );
alert( decodeURIComponent( params.c ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(location.search))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to share this solution using a bit of ESNext and a reducer.

It does pretty much the same suggested by @Carlo but it's a bit cleaner if you're comfortable with ES6 and reducers.

```
const urlSearchData = searchString => {
    if (!searchString) return false;

    return searchString
        .substring(1)
        .split('&')
        .reduce((result, next) => {
            let pair = next.split('=');
            result[decodeURIComponent(pair[0])] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);

            return result;
        }, {});
};

const searchData = urlSearchData(window.location.search);
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on @rafaelbiten's ES6 work, I added support for params that have no value and query param arrays of the duplicate entry style.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w922xefs/

```
const queryStringToJSObject = searchString => {
  if (!searchString) return null;

  return searchString
    .replace(/^\?/, '') // Only trim off a single leading interrobang.
    .split('&')
    .reduce((result, next) => {
      if (next === "") {
        return result;
      }
      let pair = next.split('=');
      let key = decodeURIComponent(pair[0]);
      let value = typeof pair[1] !== "undefined" && decodeURIComponent(pair[1]) || undefined;
      if (result.hasOwnProperty(key)) { // Check to see if this property has been met before.
        if (Array.isArray(result[key])) { // Is it already an array?
          result[key].push(value);
        }
        else { // Make it an array.
          result[key] = [result[key], value];
        }
      }
      else { // First time seen, just add it.
        result[key] = value;
      }

      return result;
    }, {}
  );
};

// Simple read of query string
const searchData = queryStringToJSObject(window.location.search);
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON Parse after stringify does the job of converting to a json with array data.

`?key1=val1&key2[]=val2.1&key2[]=val2.2&key2[]=val2.3&`

```
{
     'key1' : 'val1',
     'key2' : [ 'val2.1', 'val2.2', 'val2.3' ]
}
```

```js
function QueryParamsToJSON() {            
    var list = location.search.slice(1).split('&'),
        result = {};

    list.forEach(function(keyval) {
        keyval = keyval.split('=');
        var key = keyval[0];
        if (/\[[0-9]*\]/.test(key) === true) {
            var pkey = key.split(/\[[0-9]*\]/)[0];
            if (typeof result[pkey] === 'undefined') {
                result[pkey] = [];
            }
            result[pkey].push(decodeURIComponent(keyval[1] || ''));
        } else {
            result[key] = decodeURIComponent(keyval[1] || '');
        }
    });

    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
}

var query_string = QueryParamsToJSON();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note** --No doubt above solution works, but it wont cover all the operators

Guess you would want something like this-

```
var search = location.search;
var trimmedSearch = search.substring(1);

var searchObj = trimmedSearch?JSON.parse(
   '{"' + trimmedSearch.replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g,'":"') + '"}', 
    function(key, value) { 
       return key===""?value:decodeURIComponent(value) 
    }
)
:
{}

console.log(searchObj);
```

ex -

Override search @1st line with

```
search = "abc=foo&def=%5Basf%5D&xyz=5&foo=b%3Dar";
```

Output you get is

```
Object {abc: "foo", def: "[asf]", xyz: "5", foo: "b=ar"}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is looking just to access the search query parameters, use this function:

```
function getQueryStringValue (key)
{
    return decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.replace(new RegExp("^(?:.*[&\\?]" + encodeURIComponent(key).replace(/[\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "(?:\\=([^&]*))?)?.*$", "i"), "$1"))
}
```

Easy to use just call `getQueryStringValue(term)`

Answer (score 0):

I improved @Carlo Zottmann's solution for multiple value for a key. For example you have query like this:

```
?fruit=apple&fruit=orange&vegetable=parsley
```

it produces the result:

```
{ fruit: ['apple', 'orange'], vegetable: 'parsley' }
```

Solution:

```
function searchToObject() {
var pairs = window.location.search.substring(1).split("&"),
  obj = {},
  pair,
  i;

for ( i in pairs ) {
  if ( pairs[i] === "" ) continue;

  pair = pairs[i].split("=");

  const objectKey = decodeURIComponent(pair[0]);
  const objectValue = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
  if (obj[objectKey]) {
    obj[objectKey] = [
        obj[objectKey],
        objectValue
    ]
  } else {
    obj[objectKey] = objectValue;
  }
}

// refreshing reference
return { ...obj }; }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
const searchData = window.location.search.substring(1);
const searchObject = JSON.parse(
    '{"' +
    decodeURI(searchData)
        .replace(/"/g, '\\"')
        .replace(/&/g, '","')
        .replace(/=/g, '":"') +
    '"}'
);
```